# Trying to connect to mysql via Command line

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to link to my hosted mysql database via the command line, this is coming up

> Fatal error:Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in C:\tubekit\connect.php on line 13

This is the code in connect.php it's referring to, I can't find anything wrong.

```
$dbh = mysql_connect("$host","$username","$password") 
        or die("Cannot connect to the database: ". mysql_error());
```

The host and other details have been filled in correctly.

Comment: Your error is clear as day. "Call to undefined function mysql_connect()." You're missing the mysql php library. Look up how to install it on your machine - I'm a linux guy.

Comment: It would seem your PHP CLI does not have mysql extension. Of course you should be using mysqli or PDO anyway.

Comment: @skrilled That's probably a feature. `mysql_query` is terrible.